# ¿Como mostrar valor del <g:select> del ultimo valor guardado en grails 3.8?

Tags: grails

Estoy trabajando con Grails 3.8, tengo un formulario con un  que me trae elementos de una lista que son estatus, la cuestión es que puedo hacer cambios de estatus, y cuando recargo la pagina regresa a la primera opción, quisiera que cuando actualice, el valor del select aparezca con el ultimo estatus guardado, este es el código del select

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label class="control-label">Cambio de Estatus:</label><br>
     <g:select class="form-control" id="select" name="estatus"  from="${asignacionTesis.Estatus.list()}" value="" optionKey="id" optionValue="estatus" required="true" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes poner el valor en el atributo **value**

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label class="control-label">Cambio de Estatus:</label><br>
     <g:select class="form-control" id="select" name="estatus"  from="${asignacionTesis.Estatus.list()}" value="${asignacionTesis.estatus}" optionKey="id" optionValue="estatus" required="true" />
</div>
```